# how do I print one letter that is duplicated on string?

Tags: python, string, printing

In a string, I want to just print one letter if it happens 2 times, i tried using itertools but if the letter is written 4 times it just prints one, and I need to print 2.
Example:

```
input = rruunnnniinngg
output = running
```

Thanks btw.

Comment: what if the letter occurs 3 times?

Comment: what if the repeated letters are not adjacent?

Comment: RomanPerekhrest and kdopen it won't happen because before that I have a code that just prints the letters 2 times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `re.sub()` function (assuming only adjacent characters):

```
import re

s = 'rruunnnniinngg'
result = re.sub(r'(\S)\1', '\\1', s)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
running
```

---

- `(\S)` - regex captured group containing a single non-whitespace character
- `\1` - the value of the 1st captured group (the immediate previous character repeated)

Comment: thanks that solve my problem!!, yes the characters repeat only 2 times if anyelse reads this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from itertools import groupby
input1 = "rruunnnniinngg"
final_string = ''.join(map(lambda x: x[:(len(x)/2)], [''.join(list(b)) for a, b in groupby(input1)]))
```

Output:

```
'running'
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be simply implemented using a while loop that :
    -adds the current character in the output string
    - checks weather the next character is same as current character.
    -if yes, then it skips the next character by increasing the counter by an extra 1 unit.

```
def func(s):
    i=0
    p=''
    while(i<len(s)-1):
         p+=s[i]
         if(s[i+1]==s[i]):
            i+=1
         i+=1
    return p
```